# Input from a file (Find the nth element for the Linked List)

Tags: java, file-io, linked-list

The problem is to find nth element in a linked list, i have the problem figured out on finding the element.

But i have to read an input from a file and output the nth element from the list

For example

```
Input would look like this 
a b c d 4
e f g h 2

Output would like
a
g
```

It is stated "The first argument will be a path to a filename containing a series of space delimited characters followed by an integer representing a index into the list (1 based), one per line"

I am not sure how i would go about this? Would i first the read the file and store each line in a List?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should read the file line by line, and store each line in a `List<String>`.
Then, simply do this:

```
String line; // use an iterator on the list to get each line
String[] elements = line.trim().split("\\s");
char[] chars = new char[elements.length - 1];
int index = Integer.parseInt(elements[elements.length - 1]);
for (i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
    char[i] = elements[i].charAt(0);
```

Now you have the characters in an array ... and you said you already have the rest figured out.

Comment: in your for loop did you miss type "index" to i?

Comment: No. `index` is the last element of the line in your input file (e.g. "2" in the line "e f g h 2").

Comment: From [your next question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612168/trying-to-find-the-nth-element-to-the-last-from-a-list-with-a-file-input), I see that you are using my answer (and running into trouble in a portion of that code not in this answer) ... try not to break a simple problem into multiple small questions on SO, and if you are using someone's solution, at least accept it.