# Trying to find the nth element to the last from a list (with a file input)

Tags: java, list, file-io, arraylist

Input would look like

```
a b c d 4
e f g h 2
```

where each line would be read like a list and integer representing as an index in the list

I first try to read the file line be line and store it in the list. Heres what i have

```
public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = null;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            // File file = new File("test.txt");
            // Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }

            System.out.println(list);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Now i want to remove the white spaces from the list and store the values in char array and then i was planning on traversing that array backwards till the nth element, depending on the input for n.

```
String[] elements = line.trim().split("\\s");
char[] chars = new char[elements.length - 1];
int i= Integer.parseInt(elements[elements.length - 1]);
for (i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
    char[i] = elements[i].charAt(i);
```

Someone provided me this piece of code earlier and i tried it and it throws a nullpointerexception at String[] elements.

Comment: Are you certain line is not null at that point?

Comment: As far as I can see, the error isn't thrown in [the provided code (your previous question on SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591522/input-from-a-file-find-the-nth-element-for-the-linked-list/21591610#21591610), but in a line you have added before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are running until line is null here

```
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {   
            list.add(line);

    }
```

And then you are trying to call `.trim()` on it.

Do you mean to be processing the strings in `list` instead?

If so try looping over you list, you are already splitting it correctly and getting the last element.  All you need to do is caluclate the offset, in this case it will be the length - 1 - the last element, in you String[] elements and you can print that out.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        String currentLine = list.get(i);
        String[] elements = currentLine.trim().split("\\s");
        int lastElement = Integer.parseInt(elements[elements.length - 1]);

        String desiredValue = elements[elements.length - 1 - lastElement];
        System.out.println("desiredValue = " + desiredValue);
    }
```

Comment: Yes you are right how would i go about that part? Processing the strings in a list, when i store the values in list it looks like [a b c d 4, e f g h 2] i want it to read the a b c d 4 as one list and retrive the nth value and so on till there is no line

Comment: Added a bit to the end of my answer.  Honestly though, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for. You will need to be more specific.

Comment: you are using the same variable name `i` for both the target index you want and the loop iteration index.  Not good

Comment: I apologize about that, let me clarify.So if you have input liek shown above you have two lines. I want read of each of those lines separately as list and retrieve the nth element from the last item in the list. So for example: take the the first line and i say get the 4th element from last then my the value returned would be 'a'. Now similarly you want 2nd element from last in the second line then value would 'g'. So basically your are entering a different nth value for each line in the file till there isnt a line.

Comment: I've read this like 10 times, and I'm still confused.  So you want an array of chars for each line. Right? And then you want the nth value from the end of each line? And then what are you doing with 'a' and 'g'? Printing them? Putting them in an array? What?

Comment: @ansible with 'a' and 'g' you are just printing them out. Rest is exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: Okay - you were close, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer so others know you don't need further help.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid most of the work you're doing. I don't know if your input will require much flexibility (code to that if necessary) but in your example you only have 1 digit for the index.

Just avoid all the traversing and looping entirely:

```
        String currentLine = file.nextLine();
        //Find value from last space in the string, until the end of the string (will be the number)
        int index = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.substring(
                currentLine.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1, currentLine.length()));
        //Remove all spaces from the current line
        currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        //Remove the index at the end from the string, leaving only the characters
        currentLine = currentLine.substring(0, currentLine.indexOf(index + ""));

        char desiredValue = currentLine.charAt(currentLine.length() - index);
        System.out.println("desiredValue = " + desiredValue);
```

This saves a lot of adding stuff to arrays if none of that is needed later, just do it all the first time through.